# Hypothesis testing for the Gamma distribution - Rejection region

Tags: hypothesis-testing, gamma-distribution

Suppose under $H_0$, a test statistic $T$ has a gamma distribution with paramaters $\theta$ and $k$. Suppose also that the distribution of $T$ under $H_1$ is unknown. What is the appropriate rejection region in this case? Is it:
$$ T \geq t_\alpha$$
or 
$$\hat{T}\leq t_{1-(\alpha/2)} \hspace{0.3cm}\cup \hspace{0.3cm} \hat{T}\geq t_{\alpha/2} $$
where $\hat{T}$ is the value of the statistic $T$ for a sample $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$ and $t_\alpha$ is the critical value of the Gamma distribution with parameters $\theta$ and $k$.

Comment: Would depend on what $H_0$ and $H_1$ are.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, Would you please elaborate?

Comment: If you are testing the parameters, the critical region would depend on whether this is a left/right/both-tailed test.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, Let's say for example, the null hypothesis $H_0$ is that the sample $X_1,X_2, \ldots, X_n$ is a white noise, and $H_1$ is that the sample is not  a white noise, The statistic $T$ has a $Gamma(\theta,k)$ under $H_0$, but under $H_1$ the distribution is unkown. How would you choose the critical region in this case?

Comment: Since  the distribution of $T$ under $H_1$ is unknown, the rejection region better include the entire _negative_ real line: the observation of a negative value of $T$ is a dead giveaway that $H_0 $ cannot possibly be true and so must be rejected.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, Actually, in my case, $T$ always takes positive vlaues.

Comment: So then you _do_ know something about (or are making an assumption about) the distribution to $T$ under $H_1$, namely that$T$ takes on only positive values under $H_1$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, how can this help me choos the appropriate rejection region?

Comment: You have (somewhat fuzzily) stated a null hypothesis. What is the alternative? If you have real data, please tell us where the gamma assumption comes from and what you want to know.